# Android compiling error: cannot find symbol class Textview

Tags: android, compilation

I am getting errors when running the code during my android test app development.

```
Error:(20, 9) error: cannot find symbol class Textview
Error:(20, 38) error: cannot find symbol method findViewByID(int)
Error:(22, 35) error: cannot find symbol method FindviewbyId(int)
Error:(24, 9) error: cannot find symbol class string
Error:(26, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable brnads
```

---

Source code in FindBeerActivity is as below.

```
package com.hfad.beeradviser;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FindBeerActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_beer);
 }

//Call when the button gets clicked
public void onClickFindBeer(View view) {
    //get a reference to the Textview
    Textview brands = (TextView) findViewByID(R.id.brands) ;
    //get a reference to the Spinner
    Spinner color = (Spinner) FindviewbyId(R.id.color);
    //Get the selected item in the Spinner
    string beerType = String.valueOf(color.getSelectedItem());
    //Display the selected item
    brnads.setText(beerType);
  }
}
```

Can you help me solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were just renaming stuff incorrectly. Replace it with this:

```
//Call when the button gets clicked
public void onClickFindBeer(View view) {
    //get a reference to the Textview
    TextView brands = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.brands) ;
    //get a reference to the Spinner
    Spinner color = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.color);
    //Get the selected item in the Spinner
    String beerType = String.valueOf(color.getSelectedItem());
    //Display the selected item
    brands.setText(beerType);
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to vote my answer up and accept it as well if it solved your problem. :)